# my basic-tables.hbs isn't showing on web browser

Tags: html, node.js

my index html code is working when I clicked to hbs link in html page isn't loading.It shows my code.How can I solve my problem

my code is

```
    app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
    app.use('/',express.static(__dirname));

 app.get('/basic-tables.hbs', function (req, res) {
     
 

  



    //res.send.json(data);
        res.render("./dist/basic-tables.hbs");
      
    
      });
```

where is my mistake?
thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

```js
 app.get('/basic-table.hbs', function (req, res) {
```

Should change to

```js
 app.get('/basic-table', function (req, res) {
```

It's a route not a file path.

**Also**

You need to set the folder in which the template files are located so that express will know where to look for and render with the view engine
something like this:

```js
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
```

(`Path` is a node module you can simply load it `const path = require('path')`)

Then you will be able to simply render without needing to specify a filename like this

```js
 res.render("basic-tables");
```

because the path will already be known.

Comment: @asuscu Did you downloaded the hbs engine for express? Is it installed right?

Comment: [Well that's how you expose a view engine in express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) Maybe try [working with the library they suggest for handlebars](https://github.com/TryGhost/express-hbs) in [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/wiki#template-engines) and follow their instructions. It might be a problem with [the npm package you are working with](https://github.com/pillarjs/hbs)